# How to just calculate the diagonal of a matrix product in R

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrix `A` and `B`, so what's the fastest way to **just** calculate `diag(A%*%B)`, i.e., the inner-product of the *ith* row of `A` and *ith* column of `B`, and **the inner-product of other terms are not concerned**.

supplement: `A` and `B` have large row and column numbers respectively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708489/compute-only-diagonals-of-matrix-multiplication-in-r

Comment: It's similar but clearer as it involves only one matrix multiplication.

Comment: @akrun They are very similar, yes.  But the linked question is a pattern used in mathematics, and this does not fit that pattern.  That said, the answer to the linked question is in fact a near duplicate to the answer to this question.  The other question may admit more answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be done without full matrix multiplication, using just multiplication of matrix elements.

We need to multiply rows of `A` by the matching columns of `B` and sum the elements. Rows of `A` are columns of `t(A)`, which we multiply element-wise by `B` and sum the columns.

In other words: `colSums(t(A) * B)`

Testing the code we first create sample data:

```
n = 5
m = 10000;

A = matrix(runif(n*m), n, m);
B = matrix(runif(n*m), m, n);
```

Your code:

```
diag(A %*% B)
# [1] 2492.198 2474.869 2459.881 2509.018 2477.591
```

Direct calculation without matrix multiplication:

```
colSums(t(A) * B)
# [1] 2492.198 2474.869 2459.881 2509.018 2477.591
```

The results are the same.

Comment: @AndreyShabalin Really a smart way. I would try this first. I think probably this is the fastest way with respect to software computing, but I think there should be better way with respect to algebra.

Comment: It is numerically equivalent to `diag(A %*% B)`, the issue is there is no good name in linear algebra for `colSums` to phrase it my way.

Comment: It is not numerically equivalent to `diag(A %*% B)` because `A %*% B` performs many more multiplications. The linear algebra `colSums` would be `rep(1, m) %*% (t(A) * B)`.

Comment: It performs many more multiplications, but always produces the same result.