# Fast calculation of multiplication of vector and diagonal of matrix production?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I want to calculate `y' * diag(A' * B * A) * y`

- `y` is a `N * 1` vector
- `A` is a `m * N` matrix where `N >> m`
- `B` is a `m * m` matrix, and B is a symmetric positive definite matrix, the Cholesky decomposition `B = L * L'` is precomputed if it is needed.

Is it possible to calculate the above expression in `O(N*m)` complexity?

Comment: I'd have thought this was probably better asked on the MathWorks site.

Comment: Are there any memory limitations? In case somebody decides to benchmark various implementations - could you provide typical sizes for `N` and `m`? If you end up having to do the matrix multiplication inside `diag`, you should store `T=A.' B`, then perform `T * T.'` as mentioned [here](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=4912). You might also want to investigate the [BLAS library](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) and look for routines that perform this specific (or a similar) computation. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42569698/3372061) might be related.

Comment: @Dev-iL typical sizes are N = 2000 and m = 100

Comment: Just to clarify, what dimension do you expect the result to be?