# Product of two 3D array and a 2D matrix

Tags: arrays, r

I'm trying to find a much more efficient way to code in R the following matrix:
Let A and C be two 3D array of dimension (n, n, m) and B a matrix of dimension (m, m), then M is an (n, n) matrix such that:

> ```
> M_ij = SUM_kl A_ijk * B_kl * C_ijl
> ```

```
for (i in seq(n)) {
  for (j in seq(n)) {
    M[i, j] <- A[i,j,] %*% B %*% C[i,j,]
    }
  }
```

It is possible to write this with the TensorA package using i and j as parallel dimension, but I'd rather stay with base R object.

```r
einstein.tensor(A %e% log(B), C, by = c("i", "j"))
```

Thanks!

Comment: isn't A[I,j,] a vector? can't you write it as a single loop by omitting I or j and then doing matrix multiplication? and if you want to "drop" the loop there should be a way with apply

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would be faster, but it would avoid one level of looping:

```
for (i in seq(n))
  M[i,] <- diag(A[i,,] %*% B %*% t(C[i,,]))
```

It gives the same answer as yours in this example:

```
n <- 2
m <- 3
A <- array(1:(n^2*m), c(n, n, m))
C <- A + 1
B <- matrix(1:(m^2), m, m)

M <- matrix(NA, n, n)
for (i in seq(n))
  M[i,] <- diag(A[i,,] %*% B %*% t(C[i,,]))
M
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] 1854 3216
# [2,] 2490 4032
```

**Edited to add:**  Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/42569902/2554330, here's a slightly faster version:

```
for (i in seq(n))
  M[i,] <- rowSums((A[i,,] %*% B) * C[i,,])
```

I did some timing with `n <- 200` and `m <- 300`, and this was the fastest at 3.1 sec, versus my original solution at 4.7 sec, and the one in the question at 17.4 sec.