# vectoriced norm/matrix multiplication

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization

I have a norm that is described by the matrix `sigma`

```
sigma <- matrix(c(1,0.5,0,0.5,1,0,0,0,1),3,3))
```

To compute the norm of a vector I compute

```
t(x) %*% sigma %*% x
```

which works fine for a vector e.g. `x = 1:3`.

However i want to compute the norm of many vectors at the same time, that is I have

```
x <- t(matrix(rep(1:3, 10),3,10))
```

(of course filled with different entries).

Is there a way to compute the norm of each vector simultanuously?
I.e. something like

```
lapply(1:10, function(i) t(x[i,]) %*% sigma %*% x[i,])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
sigma <- matrix(c(1,0.5,0,0.5,1,0,0,0,1),3,3)
x <- t(matrix(rep(1:3, 10),3,10))

mynorm <- function(x, sig) t(x) %*% sig %*% x
apply(x, 1, mynorm, sig=sigma)
```

Here is a variant with `tcrossprod()`:

```
mynorm <- function(x, sig) tcrossprod(x, sig) %*% x
apply(x, 1, mynorm, sig=sigma)
```

And here is the benchmark (including variants of the solution from [compute only diagonals of matrix multiplication in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708489/compute-only-diagonals-of-matrix-multiplication-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) , thanks to @Benjamin for the link):

```
mynorm1 <- function(x, sig) t(x) %*% sig %*% x
mynorm2 <- function(x, sig) tcrossprod(x, sig) %*% x

microbenchmark(n1=apply(x, 1, mynorm1, sig=sigma), 
               n2=apply(x, 1, mynorm2, sig=sigma), 
               n3 = colSums(t(x) * (sigma %*% t(x))),
               n4 = rowSums(x * t(sigma %*% t(x))),
               n5 = rowSums(x * (x %*% t(sigma) )),
               n6 = rowSums(x * tcrossprod(x, sigma)),
               Eugen1 = diag(x %*% sigma %*% t(x)),
               Eugen2 = diag(x %*% tcrossprod(sigma, x)),
               unit="relative")
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about this simple matrix multiplication:

```
 diag(t(x) %*% sigma %*% x)
```

Edit: after the matrix multiplications you need the diagonal (of course).

Then it is faster then solutions with **apply**

Comment: This gives me "Error in t(x) %*% sigma : non-conformable arguments"

Comment: @EugenR You are calculating unneeded elements.

Comment: @EugenR Yes, could be even faster (see variant Eugen2 in the benchmark). The speed eventually depends from the dimensions of the matrices.

Answer (score 2):

This should do

```
> sigma <- matrix(c(1,0.5,0,0.5,1,0,0,0,1),3,3)
> x <- t(matrix(rep(1:30, 10),3,10))
> 
> # should give
> t(x[1, ]) %*% sigma %*% x[1, ]
     [,1]
[1,]   16
> t(x[2, ]) %*% sigma %*% x[2, ]
     [,1]
[1,]   97
> 
> # which you can get by
> rowSums((x %*% sigma) * x)
 [1]   16   97  250  475  772 1141 1582 2095 2680 3337
```

Comment: The question is close to being a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/21708489/5861244